# CMD command line: copy file to multiple locations at the same time

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I am trying to use a CMD command prompt to copy a file from one location to multiple at roughly the same time using one line of code. Is there a way to do this using [COPY](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html), [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), etc.?

I haven't been able to get this work using this type of command:

```
COPY C:\test.txt C:\A1\ C:\A2\
```

It seems like this should work, but it gives an error that the syntaxes of the command is incorrect (copy) or invalid number of parameters (xcopy).

I would like to avoid a batch file because of the way this needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Create a batch file that has all your target locations:

```
@echo off
Copy %1 targetPath1
Copy %1 targetPath2
Copy %1 targetPath3
...
```

Then call that with your source file path as an argument.

The call will be 1 line  :-).

Answer (score 2):

One line of code only? It is ugly, but possible:

```
for %i in ("c:\A1","c:\my folder","c:\A2") do copy test.txt %i
```

(If you use it within a batch file, replace every `%i` with `%%i`.)

Comment: instead of `copy test.txt %i` you should state `copy "test.txt" "%~i"` to avoid trouble with paths containing spaces and/or some other poisonous characters...

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP asked for copying the file to multiple locations **at the same time**,
I would add this solution:

```
for %D in ("C:\A1\", "C:\A2\") do (start /B "Copy to %D" cmd /c "echo Copying file to %D... & copy your_file %D")
```

Used this to distribute a package to seven flash drives...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative -- the command separator `&`:

```
copy "test.txt" "C:\A1\" & copy "test.txt" "C:\A2\"
```

or:

```
xcopy "test.txt" "C:\A1\" & xcopy "test.txt" "C:\A2\"
```