# Update file across multiple folder locations?

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I need something that can copy a specified file any and everywhere on my drive (or computer) where that file already exists; i.e. update a file.  I tried to search this site, in case I'm not the first, and found this:

[CMD command line: copy file to multiple locations at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404807/cmd-command-line-copy-file-to-multiple-locations-at-the-same-time)

But not quite the same.

Example: 
Say I have a file called CurrentList.txt, and I have copies of it all over my hard drive.  But then I change it and I want all the copies to update.  So I want to copy the newer one over all the others.  It *could* 'copy if newer', but generally I know it's newer, so it could also just find every instance and copy over it.

I was originally going to use some kind of .bat file that would have to iterate over every folder seeking the file in question, but my batch file programming is limited/rusty.  Then I looked to see if xcopy could do it, but I don't think so...

For how I will use it most, I generally know where those files are going to be, so it actually might be as good or better if I could specify it to (using example), "copy CurrentList.txt, overwriting all other copies wherever found in the C:\Lists folder and all subfolders".

I would really like to be able to have it in a context menu, so I could (from a file explorer) right click on a file or selected files and choose the option to distribute it.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Try checking `find /?` and `findstr /?`

Answer (score 2):

Use the "replace" command...

```
replace CurrentList.txt C:\Lists /s
```

Comment: Thank you!  I should have been aware of that.  I know I can make that into a batch file, something like:    "replace %1 C:\Lists /s".   But is there a way to integrate it into a context menu such that the filename variable would be sent to the batch file?

Comment: After attempting that, I got "Extended Error 32".  I presume this happened because it was trying to replace a file with itself.  Maybe I should have mentioned that the file will originate from a subfolder of C:\Lists..  Actually, I see that using the /u option is a fair work-around for the error.

Comment: You can ignore that "Extended Error 32". You'll get then when you try to replace files in a folder and the "source file" is located in that folder as well. All the other files will still be replaced even when you get that error.

Comment: Actually no, error 32 interrupted the batch.  But the /u option worked fine.

Comment: Add the /U switch if the source file (and latest version) is in the directories.